# How do you pass a JavaScript variable to your Groovy controller?

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have been searching on Google for a really good while, and I cannot find a solution to this problem. I am trying to access a JavaScript variable from my GSP file in my Groovy controller, but I can't find out how to do this.

Example:

```
//JavaScript stuff
<script>
    function validateForm(){
         var ret = false
    }
</script>

//Groovy controller stuff
def myAction = {
    println params.ret
}
```

How do I achieve something similar to this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet (with session at least)?

Comment: I have tried remoteFunction but I get a java script error so it might work but I dont know the syntax of it. This is how I have it in my javascript `${remoteFunction(controller: ActionsController, action:'ImplementNewPixel', params: 'ret')}` But no I have not tried anything with sessions yet. How would you use sessions?

Comment: You should be able to pass the variable using remoteFunction. Have a look at the way params are passed in [remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to pass a variable to the controller:

1. [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)
2. Form submit

**Ajax**

- Use `remoteFunction`

  ```
  ${remoteFunction(controller: 'actionsController' , action: 'implementNewPixel', params: '\'ret=\' + ret')}
  ```
- Use Ajax

  ```
  var ret = false;
  jQuery.ajax({
      url: "${createLink(controller: 'actionsController', action: 'implementNewPixel')}",
      data: "ret=" + ret,
      success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
      }
  });
  ```

etc.

**Form submit**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ret;
    function validateForm(){
        ret = false;
    }

    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("[name='jftForm']").submit(function () {
            jQuery("[name='ret']").val(ret);
        });
    });
</script>

<g:form name="jftForm" controller="actionsController" action="implementNewPixel">
    ...
    <g:hiddenField name="ret" value=""/>
    <g:submitButton name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</g:form>
```

Comment: I have tried both of your methods but I still cannot access the variable in my controller. Would I be able to access it by using `params.ret` in my controller? Also when I try using the Form submit method, I get a java script error like so `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ImplementNewPixel:133 (anonymous function)`

Comment: Include jQuery in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentaton](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html).

`params: '\'ret=\' + ret'`